# How to display fix banner between QMenubar and QToolBar in QMainWindow

Tags: qt

How can I show fixed banner (with some widget like label and button ) in between 
QMenuBar and QToolBar ?
Similarly like QStatusBar but in  between QMenuBar and QToolBar.
I tried to implement using QToolBar.

```
 // toolbar Banner with lable inside it.
 QLabel * bannerLabel = new QLabel(" bannerToobar with label banner.");
 bannerLabel->setAlignment( Qt::AlignVCenter );
 ui.bannerToobar->addWidget( bannerLabel );
 ui.bannerToobar->setAllowedAreas(Qt::ToolBarArea::TopToolBarArea);
 ui.bannerToobar->setMovable( false );


 QSize banner_sz = ui.bannerToobar->size();
 ui.bannerToobar->setFixedHeight( banner_sz.height() * 2 );
 QSizePolicy banner_szPolicy( QSizePolicy::Policy::Maximum,  QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed );

 banner_szPolicy.setHorizontalStretch(255);
 ui.bannerToobar->setSizePolicy( banner_szPolicy );
```

but i can't prevent user from draging mainToolbar and droping in the same row as my 
bannerToolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force it to wrap initially using [QMainWindow::addToolBarBreak](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html#addToolBarBreak), but I don't know a way to prevent it from being put back there later by the user (except for making the toolbars non-moveable).

If there was a QToolbar::dockLocationChanged signal (which seems to have been requsted and resolved in https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-1274, but I still don't see the signal anywhere), I suppose you could use insertToolBarBreak to fix it up whenever things have changed. Maybe there's some hackish way you could get notified when the toolbars move.

Or you could use QMainWindow::setMenuWidget to place a widget containing both your QMenuBar and something else into the menu area of the QMainWindow. This could get tricky if you want to support styles (mac/gnome/etc) where the menubar gets lifted out of your window to the top-of-screen and the toolbar gets unified with the window title decorations. But the idea of a banner between menubar and toolbar just naturally has problems in such cases :-)

Comment: Thanks, @puetzk I will use setMenuWidget,beasue my application is so far Windows only.